# Cython - Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'float *'

Tags: python, cython

I am using Cython to write a Python API to a C project.

In the C project there is the following relevant code in the header file:

```
#ifndef EN_API_FLOAT_TYPE
  #define EN_API_FLOAT_TYPE float
#endif

int DLLEXPORT ENgetlinkvalue(int index, int property, EN_API_FLOAT_TYPE *value);
```

In my .pyx file I have:

```
cdef extern from "epanet2.h":
    int ENgetlinkvalue(int, int, float *)

def engetlinkvalue(int index, int proprty, float *value):
    return ENgetlinkvalue(index, proprty, value)
```

When I run setup.py I get the following error:

### def engetlinkvalue(int index, int proprty, float *value):
^

src\cyepanet.pyx:48:43: Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'float *'

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this one out (oh, and also searching SO, Cython documentation, a book on Cython, ChatGPT, and Copilot)

I am sure this is an easy one for someone more experienced in C coding.  For me, 99% of my experience is in Python.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, I get the same error when I replace 'def' with 'cpdef'.

Comment: Yes, I want to call it from Python. 
I have successfully implemented other function calls such as: 
cdef extern from "epanet2.h": 
    int ENepanet(const char *, const char *, const char *) 

def enepanet(char *f1, char *f2, char *f3): 
    return ENepanet(f1, f2, f3) 

But for some reason the float type is giving me issues.

Comment: What does the underlying function *do* with this pointer? Pointers are not a thing Python code can work with. `float *` is not a type with any reasonable counterpart in Python (outside of ctypes, but forcing people to use ctypes would defeat the purpose of writing a Python interface to this code in the first place). The glue layer you're writing will have to expose a different API to Python than the API exposed by the C library.

Comment: I believe in the C code the function is storing the returned data of interest in the "value" variable.  To your point, yes, when I call this in my Python API, I would like to return the "value" instead of an integer.  The C code always returns an integer which is an error code with a value of 0 being no error.  I typically do error trapping in other ways like with Try-Except.

Comment: If it helps, here is the function call from the .c file:

int DLLEXPORT EN_getlinkvalue(EN_Project p, int index, int property, double *value)
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
**  Input:   index = link index
**           property = link property code (see EN_LinkProperty)
**  Output:  value = link property value
**  Returns: error code
**  Purpose: retrieves a property value for a link
**----------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as you say in the comments) the float is being used as a return value, then you'd do something like

```
def engetlinkvalue(int index, int proprty):
    cdef float value
    errCode = ENgetlinkvalue(index, proprty, &value)
    if errCode:
        ... # raise an exception
    return value
```

That converts it to a nicer Python interface - you use `return` to send back a value (as you would in Python) and you use Python exceptions to indicate a failure.

It's often a good idea in these cases to think about the Python interface you'd like rather than trying to match the C interface. (This is pretty much what @user2357112 also says in the comments)

Comment: Thank you DavidW and @user2357112, this worked.  Seems like it should have been obvious, now that you have shown me the way. :)  Thanks for the quick replies too, this has made my day!